# Drag and drop, editors

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How can I make a drag and drop editor like the one in wufoo.com form editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually client side applications are built using some sort of **client-side framework**.
The more popular ones are (in no particular order):

- [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/)
- [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/)
- [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

Start by checking those out, maybe try one or two tutorials, that should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

For client side web applications, you can always look at the source.

And beware not to copy it 100%, just use it as a source of knowledge and use your imagination to create something new.